# How to get dropdown selected value in app.py in python flask?

Tags: python, flask

I have a dropdown list in abc.html in python flask templates.  how to get dropdown selected value in app.py, on the dropdown select event.

```
@app.route("/")def abc(): return render_template('abc.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use Javascript to invoke an AJAX request back to the API server with some data containing that information.

In other words, there's a logical separation between the displayed HTML (front-end) and the Python code (backend). The only ways to communicate between them is by websockets or HTTP traffic